# Bind error: no current owner name error when running named-checkzone

Tags: debian, bind

Using Debian Jessie.

I try to configue my bind zone, but I'm getting errors when I check it with `named-checkzone`. One error is "no current owner name".

```
root@host:/etc# named-checkzone test /etc/bind/db.test.domain
/etc/bind/db.test.domain:2: no current owner name
/etc/bind/db.test.domain:4: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/db.test.domain:6: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/db.test.domain:7: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/db.test.domain:9: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/db.test.domain:10: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/db.test.domain:13: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/db.test.domain:14: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/db.test.domain:15: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/db.test.domain:16: no TTL specified; zone rejected
zone test/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/db.test.domain failed: no owner
zone test/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Here is the /etc/bind/db.test.domain file:

```
        IN  NS  ns

_spf        TXT "v=spf1 ip4:111.222.133.0/22 mx exists:%{1}.%{i}._spf ?all"

@       MX  50  mail.domain.com.
@       TXT "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.sub.domain.com"

mail.domain.com     A   111.222.133.144
mail.domain.com     AAAA    2000:888:8888:11::199


@       A   111.222.133.155
@       AAAA    2000:777:7777:11::199
www     A   111.222.133.155
www     AAAA    2000:777:7777:11::199
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add first line in zone file.

```
$TTL 3600
```

Add SOA record

```
@   IN SOA master.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
    2017030300 ; serial
    3600       ; refresh
    1800       ; retry
    604800     ; expire
    600 )      ; ttl
```

Comment: What should be master.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. replaced?

Comment: master.example.com. = Primary master name server for this zone (NS); hostmaster.example.com. = email for zone = hostmaster@example.com

Comment: Your answer helped me to fix the problem. Thanks!